# How add this non clickable line (see on picture) to ListView with multi text in row?

Tags: android, listview, helper, multiline

could someone help me how to add this selected line which you can see on picture to ListView (I mean lines as "General, Incoming calls, etc."). I have made ListView using a HashMap, but I don't know how to add this line to my ListView. I'll be very thankful if anybody help me.

**Picture here:** http://img11.imageshack.us/img11/1795/sc20111010202936.jpg

Comment: Well the desired can be achieved in two ways:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can easily be done with preferences and is called a preference category here is a good tutorial on preferences

http://www.kaloer.com/android-preferences

Answer (score 0):

The Desired List View can be achieved in two ways:

1.Creating a Section List View [Click here for Help](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-sectioned-headers-in-listviews/)

2.You can use the text with that background image in your xml for infalter layout.

And make it visible and invisible accordingly of your categorization.

Hope this would help you and guide to right path